# Android varied image position alignment in single layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a game with circular buttons. I am thinking about a strategy that allows me to display variety of buttons in variety of positions in the same screen in an efficient way. 
Like, 
Sample images:
Image 1: 1 button

[image]

Image 4: 4 Buttons

[image]

The game works on seconds and I want the images to be changing so smoothly and should not take much time for transition. My ideas to implement this are below. Please advise me the best way to achieve this.

1. Use Grid view and populate items as required.
2. Use Open GL to display buttons.
3. Use a fragment and assign layouts as required.
4. Any other perfect way you suggest.

Note: I don't use strips to animate. All I want to do is just to do some calculation according to which button the player picks to click. And my concerns are,
1. Quick and smooth transition of layouts.

please guide me to pick the right path.

Thanks,
Karthick.

Comment: `I was about to include image samples but did not have enough reputations.` Post your images on imgur or other services and add link to the question. Someone with higher reputation can then edit your question and embeed images.

Comment: Thank you Marcin Orlowski. I have included two links as my reputation allows only two.

Thanks.

Comment: I did not completely understand what you want to achieve.Could you please be a bit more specific about what you want to achieve?

Anyways, I can assure you that openGL is not really any near the best way to deal with this.The grid view population thingy might work though.

Anyways, if I get more information I might be able to help you in a more detailed way and also give you examples.

Comment: Hi Vlad,
I need to achieve.
1. The activity changes every second automatically.
2. It shows different number of images in different formations. For example, An activity shows 5 images. Next second it shows 2 images and it goes on.
3. My important concern is, the player just has only one second to react for one formation. So the loading of that page with images should be as fast as possible.
Thanks a lot for your interest to help.